# How to display a Custom Block in front page which contains the drupal_get_form(formid)

Tags: drupal

Hi friends i have developed a custom block which gets the form from existing module,It is working fine for page which has the form id as parameter but in other pages i am getting this error/warning.
call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'simplenews_subscription_manager_form' not found or invalid function name in /var/www/rajesh/ph/drupal/includes/form.inc on line 382.

Can any one show me the solution to display this form in every page or front page.

Thanks in advance,
Rajesh

Answer (score 1):

This is a drupal based question. Please posted on [drupal stackexchange.](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/) for quick reply

```
<?php
module_load_include('inc', 'simplenews', 'simplenews.subscription');
print drupal_get_form('simplenews_subscription_manager_form');
?>
```

use like this

Comment: Thanks dude it is working thanks a lot and can you please help how to get it in popup.